# How can I close dialog widget after receiving data in a text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `buildShowDialog` that loads in `initState` and in my Text widget when I receive some data I want to close the `buildShowDialog`. How can I do this ?

The buildshowDialog method

```
 buildShowDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
  }
```

calling it in `initState`

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    buildShowDialog(context);
}
```

Now in my widget when I get some data in my text widget from the provider package I want to dismiss the dialog then

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
\\\
return Scaffold(
 body: Stack(
 \\\
Consumer < AppData > (
    builder: (ctx, prod, child) => dropOffText ?
    Text(
        prod.dropOffLocation != null ?
        prod.dropOffLocation 
          ***CALL NAVIGATOR.POP HERE! *** (close the dialog here)   
          :
        "Pick your destination ",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ) :
    Text("Pick your destination "),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in different ways like without showing the dialog in init state, You can use FutureBuilder Instead like below

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
future: _getData,
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.connectionState!=ConnectionState.done) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else Text(snapshot.data);
  },
)
```

or you can use also [this](https://pub.dev/packages/progress_dialog) package instead

Comment: You are probably right, I will try your suggestion but for now can you help me with how I could close the dialog box if my `dropOffLocation ` is not null ? Reason being now the circular progress bar is within the text only